# Stopping Comcast from turning router into a hotspot

Tags: router

Comcast has announced intentions to turn comcast owned end-point routers into public hotspots:
http://money.cnn.com/2014/06/16/technology/security/comcast-wifi-hotspot/

I noticed xfinitywifi network has appeared in my neighborhood so I know they are doing it in my neighborhood.  I have also noticed the xfinitywifi networks around town so I know they are doing this in businesses as well.

Here is the official way to turn it off:
http://www.tomsguide.com/us/how-to-disable-xfinity-wifi,news-19036.html

I would also like to disable it in such way that I am confident that it will not inadvertently be turned back on.  Examples of inadvertent are: a) Comcast changes their terms such that it allows them to turn it on, or b) Comcast offers some incentive, but in the fine print of the conditions it gives them the right to turn it back on.

One technique is a faraday cage; if that is your suggestion, please elaborate on a simple way to do that such as something that I can easily buy or do.

I am using my own wifi enabled router, so I don't care about disabling the wifi on their router.

Comment: If you cannot trust Comcast, find a new ISP.

Comment: if you have your own wifi then just remove the wifi antenna in the comcast router.

Comment: Just unplug it for a minute. Easy.

Comment: If you could adjust the question from being an x y problem - your real issue is ensuring the comcast wifi sharing thing is turned off, I can see it being on superuser. I'd suggest keeping an open mind to non faraday cage solutions.

Comment: Coat your router and antennas with a lead based paint.

Comment: If Comcast has been paying sufficient attention to the quality of the service they are deploying, there would be no reason to turn it off. If you don't trust Comcast to have been paying attention to the quality of this service then I tend to agree with EEAA.

Comment: If you want to build a Faraday cage, I'd try covering a shoe box with tinfoil, and putting the router in there. However, due to the lack of air transfer, maybe the device can overheat.